# Network diverges with NaN in simple TensorFlow example

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I am trying to follow the example from [Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/notes_03.pdf) series on TF by implementing a quadratic linear regression.

```
Y = W*X*X + u*X + b
```

The dataset can be found in [Cengage](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understandable_statistics/7e/students/datasets/slr/frames/slr05.html) dataset; and the code is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import xlrd

DATA = 'data\\slr05.xls'

# Read data
data = xlrd.open_workbook(DATA, encoding_override='utf-8')
sheet = data.sheet_by_index(0)
dataset = np.asarray([sheet.row_values(i) for i in range(1, sheet.nrows)])
n_samples = sheet.nrows - 1

X = tf.placeholder('float', name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder('float', name = 'Y')

W = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'weights')
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'bias')
u = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'u_weight')

Y_ = X*X*W + X*u + b

loss = tf.square(Y - Y_, name = 'loss')

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

loss_average = []

# Start the Session
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(10):
        for x, y in dataset:
            print(sess.run([optimizer, Y_, W, b, u, X, Y], feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y}))
            loss_average.append(sess.run(loss, feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y}))
```

The final W, b, and u values that I get are `nan`. I tried to check step-by-step why this is happening. So, in the output below I have included the `[optimizer, Y_, W, b, u, X, Y]`

and after a few row iterations I get:

```py
[None, 3.9304674e+33, -1.0271335e+33, -7.7725354e+29, -2.8294217e+31, 36.2, 41.]
[None, -1.619979e+36, inf, 3.2321854e+32, 1.2834338e+34, 39.7, 147]
```

Apparently, during optimization the `W` ends up to 'inf', which breaks down the regression output.

Any, idea what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an exploding gradient problem here. That's because your ***X*** and ***Y***, and consequently difference values are in the magnitude of ***10<sup>1</sup>***, so the square differences (you loss) are of magnitude ***10<sup>2</sup>***. When you introduce the ***X<sup>2</sup>*** into the regression, your difference values will be in the magnitude of ***10<sup>2</sup>***, their squares of magnitude ***10<sup>4</sup>***. Therefore the gradients will be much larger and the network diverges violently.

To correct for this, you can reduce the learning rate by a factor of ***10<sup>-3</sup>***, to put the gradients roughly back where they were, and lo and behold, this code (tested):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import xlrd

DATA = 'slr05.xls'

# Read data
data = xlrd.open_workbook(DATA, encoding_override='utf-8')
sheet = data.sheet_by_index(0)
dataset = np.asarray([sheet.row_values(i) for i in range(1, sheet.nrows)])
n_samples = sheet.nrows - 1

X = tf.placeholder('float', name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder('float', name = 'Y')

W = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'weights')
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'bias')
u = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'u_weight')

Y_ = X*X*W + X*u + b
#Y_ = X * u + b

loss = tf.square(Y - Y_, name = 'loss')

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0000001).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

loss_average = []

# Start the Session
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(10):
        for x, y in dataset:
            print(sess.run([optimizer, loss, Y_, W, b, u, X, Y], feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y}))
            loss_average.append(sess.run(loss, feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y}))
```

will obediently and orderly converge, as nice networks do, outputting (last 5 lines only):

> [None, 1313.2705, 9.760924, 0.06911032, 0.0014081484, 0.010015297, array(11.9, dtype=float32), array(46., dtype=float32)]
>   [None, 1174.7083, 7.7259817, 0.06986606, 0.0014150032, 0.010087272, array(10.5, dtype=float32), array(42., dtype=float32)]
>   [None, 1217.4297, 8.1083145, 0.07066501, 0.0014219815, 0.01016194, array(10.7, dtype=float32), array(43., dtype=float32)]
>   [None, 657.74097, 8.353538, 0.07126329, 0.0014271108, 0.010217336, array(10.8, dtype=float32), array(34., dtype=float32)]
>   [None, 299.5538, 1.6923765, 0.07134304, 0.0014305722, 0.010233952, array(4.8, dtype=float32), array(19., dtype=float32)]

Comment: Aha! That’s very interesting. I will try and manually do the maths to get a better idea